# How do I store a mongodb query result in a variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am having the hardest time finding a solution to something that should be so simple.. I would like to find a document in a mongo database and store it in a variable that i can use anywhere in a node.js app..

The closest I think I have gotten is

```
var path = db.collection('paths').find().toArray()
```

where path is a collection holding one document, but then `console.log(path[0])` returns undefined..

Comment: Finding documents from mongodb is asynchronous, so generally you won't assign the return value of the function to a variable, but instead will pass in a callback which receives the result of the query, as you can see in the examples https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-all-documents

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201528

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try asynchronous way, something like this

```
var path;
db.collection('paths', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        path = results;
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

**NOTE**

Never try to run IO operation synchronously in node.js because node.js is single threaded. If you do, you would block the whole application. The api provided by mongodb nodejs native is asynchronous, that means the result is expected in some point of time in future but not immediately. As soon as the result is available callback function is called and you get your result.

If you are coming from synchronous coding background, its a paradigm shift. You need to change your mind to think asynchronously.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, the results are logged just fine within the toArray method but then outside of it path is still undefined

Comment: Thats why its called asynchronous. Why do you need path outside the callback block?

Comment: Moreover you can't have it outside the callback block. You need to wait till the result is received and execute all your logic inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm late answering to this question. I've started working with `nodejs` and I'm using MongoDB for store all the data and I had the same problem finding a solution to keep the documents in a variable.

As you may know, the queries are async and in that way you can't assign the result in a variable, instead of doing that you have to use a function as a callback and return the value there.

Here's a sample code that I'm using in my project:

```
var verifyUserExists = function(db, callback, username) {

  var collection = db.collection('users');

  collection.findOne({ 'login': username }, function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    callback(doc);
  });

}

mongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');

  verifyUserExists(db, function(userExists) {
    console.log(userExists);
    db.close();
  }, username);
});
```

If you want to do other operations with the returned documents you have to do it in the callback, if you try to return the value in the callback function to a global variable you will get `undefined` because the code is executed async.