# MongoDB: cursor.toArray returns Promise { <pending> }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-cursor

### Situation

I wrote a query:

```
var results = db.collection('diseases').find({
  'ttl.txt': {
    $regex: data,
    $options: 'i'
  }
}).toArray();
```

### Problem

Then I printed `results` to a console.

```
if (results.length > 0) {
  console.log(results);
}
```

ToArray method must return array of found documents. But this method returns me this string: `Promise { <pending> }`.

### Question

How can I return array of found documents instead of this string?

### PS

toArray: [Link to the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting this error because the find() method is asynchronous, that's why the promise is pending: it is still fetching.

```
db.collection('diseases').find({
  'ttl.txt': {
    $regex: data,
    $options: 'i'
  }
}).toArray().then((data) => {
    // Here you can do something with your data
    doSomethingWithTheResult(result)
})
```

Notice that you have your data inside a callback. For more info about promises check [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Depending on your node version (7.6+ I believe), you can use something like this

```
async function getResults() {
    return db.collection('diseases').find({
        'ttl.txt': {
        $regex: data,
        $options: 'i'
        }
    }).toArray();
}

const results = await getResults();
```

So your code with look like a synchronous code. The key here is the async/await command that wait for the promise results.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The return type of `find()` is defined as a Cursor:  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find  whereas the return type of `Cursor.toArray` is a Promise:  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#toArray.  Is it possible to just do this:  `var result = await db.collection('diseases').find(query).toArray();` and add the `async` keyword to the enclosing function?

Comment: I never used it like that, but if to Array() returns a promise you can await on it just like you said

Comment: @Denis I stumbled across this answer looking for a solution to the same problem, but I would like some clarification if you wouldn't mind providing. Why to we need to do `.toArray().then(...)` for the `find()` function, but for the `findAndModify()` function, we can use `doc.value` right in the callback. Is `findAndModify()` not asynchronous?

Comment: It's a bit late, but I hope I can still help. Since you pass a callback to the findAndModify() it will internally wait for the find to finish and then run your callback, that's why you can acess it directly. It doesn't mean the method itself is synchronous (that's why you need a callback) it just means that the method will run your callback at the right moment

Answer (score 1):

In the `toArray()` method you write a callback function:

```
var results = db.collection('diseases').find({
  'ttl.txt': {
    $regex: data,
    $options: 'i'
  }
}).toArray(function(err, result) {
     if (results.length > 0) {
       console.log(results);
     }
});
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to use the callback function within toArray it never fires. If I use the answer after yours it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

A modern approach using async/await.
In this case, we want to get matching bird colors in the birds collection.

```
async function getBirdsByColor(color) {
    try {
        var birds = await db.collection('birds').find({
            color: color
        }).toArray()

        if(!birds || !birds.length) {
            throw('No birds with color: ' + color)
        }
        console.log('Successfully found one or more birds:', birds)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Bird search failure: ', e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is giving because it's a promise

```
var results = db.collection('diseases').find({
    'ttl.txt': {
            $regex: data,
            $options: 'i'
    }
}).lean().then(function (obj) {
    if (!obj) {
            return resolve('not find');
    }

    return resolve(obj);
}).catch(function (err) {


    return reject(err);
});
```